# Aligning Text View with constraint Layout

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to align my textview in the constraint layout without using margins so the layout can be responsive in all the devices but so far I am stuck in positioning. Here is my code and expected output attached in the image. I just want to make the amount align slightly with currency text. [image: This is the expected output]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/year_bar_chart_total"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Total"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         />
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/yearBarChartCurrency"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="RM"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/yearBarChartAmount"
         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.17"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/year_bar_chart_total"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/year_bar_chart_total"
         tools:text="RM"/>
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/yearBarChartAmount"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="tOTAL"
         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.17"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/yearBarChartCurrency"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/year_bar_chart_total"
         tools:text="233.34"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Anyone got an Idea?

Comment: It is aligned at the top isn't it?

Comment: @forpas Yeah i am trying to make it as in the picture without using any margins

Comment: Then change the fontsize because you want the amount bigger and you're done.

Comment: @forpas Okay do you think is there a better solution than that? may be using ratios etc..

Comment: The fontsize unit is `sp` and it serves this purpose to make sizes easier to scale in different devices. Choose a fontsize for currency say 12sp and make the amount double 24sp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use guidelines to achieve this :**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="balance"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RM"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="233.34"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />
```

**It will look like this:**

[image]

I must emphasize one thing that really bothered me:

*"margins so the layout can be responsive in all the devices"* - this is  not true and let me explain.

what makes your screen responsive to all screen sizes is [constraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) and how you use it, I agree that a large number of margin in `dp` will make your screen not responsive **but** small margins are recommended to use in google material design - it will actually give your app better look and prevent your views from being  attached directly to the parent border.

Comment: agree @Tammir Abutbul

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to align the tops of the text.

A `TextView` has an internal structure based upon the typography of the font. ["Android 101: Typography"](https://proandroiddev.com/android-and-typography-101-5f06722dd611) has a good explanation of Android typography. This [diagram](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1500/1*v1FDlH-vFEnhXDFDxp6OXg.png) is particularly useful.

So, the following layout looks like this in design view. As you can see, the tops of the text do not line up.

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4778C5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/year_bar_chart_total"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:text="Balance"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yearBarChartCurrency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RM"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/year_bar_chart_total"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/year_bar_chart_total"
        tools:text="RM" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yearBarChartAmount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="4sp"
        android:paddingLeft="4sp"
        android:text="233.34"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/yearBarChartCurrency"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/yearBarChartCurrency" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Although the fonts of the `TextViews` are the same, the different font sizes prevent alignment of the tops of the actual text even though the `TextViews` have their tops align. This is because the metrics differ.

So, to align the *actual* tops of the text, we need to determine how far below the `TextView` tops the actual text starts and shift the text by those amounts. The following code does this. Comments are in the code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView yearBarChartAmount = findViewById(R.id.yearBarChartAmount);
        TextView yearBarChartCurrency = findViewById(R.id.yearBarChartCurrency);
        yearBarChartCurrency.setTranslationY(-getTopOfText(yearBarChartCurrency));
        yearBarChartAmount.setTranslationY(-getTopOfText(yearBarChartAmount));
    }

    private int getTopOfText(TextView textView) {
        // Force measure of text pre-layout.
        textView.measure(0, 0);

        // bounds will store the rectangle that will circumscribe the text.
        Rect bounds = new Rect();

        // Get the bounds for the text. Top and bottom are measured from the baseline. Left
        // and right are measured from 0.
        String text = (String) textView.getText();
        textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        return textView.getBaseline() + bounds.top;
    }
}
```

The following is what is displayed:

[image]

There may be other considerations, but this is the gist of the solution. It may be worthwhile to encapsulate this into a custom `TextView`.